# why can't I hold three boxes side-by-side?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am using twitter bootstrap v2.3.2. I am trying to put three divs side-by-side but third one goes to the under.

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="span4">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="none" />
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
           <jdoc:include type="modules" name="middle" style="none" />
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="none" />
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing your 'row' classed div, code should be like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="none" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="middle" style="none" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="none" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```